# GEE- NDWI from Landsat 4

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to create image collection of NDWI for a polygon I have from 1983-2019.
For that, I want to use different Landsat image collection.
I saw that there is made a product in Google Earth Engine that gives the NDWI values, but I face few problems, the first one is that I want to represent and download the whole image collection, and the second is that whenever I try to represent even one image I don't see anything. I tried also to represent only one but I still see nothing.

This is the code I wrote.

```
// create image collections for the years 1983-2019 


//Landsat 4 
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_8DAY_NDWI')
                  .filterDate('1983-01-01', '1984-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(table);
print('dataset: ', dataset);


// Get the number of images Landsat4
var count = dataset.size();
print('Count: ',count);

// Sort by a cloud cover property, get the least cloudy image- why does it rank the images? do they still have clouds?
var image = ee.Image(dataset.sort('CLOUD_COVER').first());
print('Least cloudy image: ', image);

var colorized = dataset.select('NDWI');
var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: ['0000ff', '00ffff', 'ffff00', 'ff0000', 'ffffff'],
};
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(colorized, colorizedVis, 'Colorized');
Map.addLayer(image,colorizedVis,'Hi');
```

Comment: I don't know where your study area is ("table"), but there is quite limited data present in 1984, mainly restricted to the USA [link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/709123b21f63ec1ef2732e9f2adbec57)

Comment: it's in Africa, Nigeria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kuik says, data in early 1980 is limited to the US, so is hard to find data out these limits before 1990.

Also `.filterBounds(table)` is not useful in this kind of data, because is a global composite product. So I don't recommend you to download the whole collection.

A workaround is working with Collection-1, filter bounds, compute NDWI and download products. To compute NDWI use:

```
var NDWI = function(img){
  var result = img.normalizedDifference(['B4','B5']).rename('NDWI');
  return result.copyProperties(img);
};

//Landsat 4 
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_TOA")
                  .filterDate('1983-01-01', '1984-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(table).map(NDWI);
print('dataset: ', dataset);
```

But, sadly, you will find no images in Africa in this date range

Comment: sorry for the question but do you know why  there are no images from that time?  Do you have any idea how can I get images of Africa from this date range?

Comment: 1) For technical reasons (check: https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/1-s2.0-S0034425715302194-main.pdf). 2) You can try with https://glovis.usgs.gov

Comment: so if I don't see the images, but do get data about them (like how many images are and more), can I still run statistics on them? I need the mean NDWI vaue or the whole image